# Regex and beautifulsoup returning "'NoneType' object is not callable" error

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I am trying to implement the regex query at http://regexr.com/3dnut.

This is my code so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
r = urllib.urlopen('http://www.indeed.com/resumes?q=banking&l=london&co=GB&start=0').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(r, "lxml")
letters = soup.search("\/r\/([^:\/\s]+)\/(\w+)")
print letters
```

I am expecting an array of matches, but instead I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/cv-scraper/main.py", line 5, in <module>
    letters = soup.search("\/r\/([^:\/\s]+)\/(\w+)")
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

How do I resolve it?

Comment: if you want a list of answers try `soup.find_all()`

Comment: @m_callens - thanks, how would I implement my regex into `findall`

Comment: the exact same way, `soup.find_all(r'\/r\/([^:\/\s]+)\/(\w+)')` and assuming its a valid regex and WILL have matches, it'll return a list of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `search()` method in `BeautifulSoup`. The reason it throws this particular error is that the dot-notation has a special meaning - it is a shortcut to `find()`. `soup.search` is basically transformed into `soup.find("search")` which would try to find a tag `search`. It fails and returns `None` which then is being called. What you ended up with is `None("\/r\/([^:\/\s]+)\/(\w+)")` which fails with `None` is not callable, of course.